# How to prove a set must have a specific number of elements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Trying to understand sets but having a hard time. Could someone help me through this one?

Let A be a set of six positive integers each of which is less than 13.  Show that there must be two distinct subsets of A whose elements, when added together, give the same sum.

I know subsets that you could get, but how would you actually prove that you will always get the same sum if you add two subsets together?

Comment: Hint: use the pigeonhole principle

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Our set has $2^6$, that is, $64$ subsets. The sum of a subset of our numbers is at most $12+11+10+9+8+7$. that is, $57$.  (There will in fact be more than $2$ subsets with the same sum.)